# Java Generics E extends Comparable<E>

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to implement a ConcurrentSortedList in Java and I have the following:

```
public class ConcurrentLinkedList<E> extends AbstractCollection<E>
```

The above compiles fine, however if I change it to

```
public class ConcurrentLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>> extends     AbstractCollection<E extends Comparable<E>>
```

I get an error

```
> expected

wrong number of type arguments; required 1
```

What is the right Syntax? I want E to be an object that implements the Comparable interface

---

I made changed the code to

```
public class ConcurrentLinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>> extends AbstractCollection<E>
```

and it compiles, However the following code is now giving an error:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
checkNullArg(e);
for (;;) {
  Node<E> n = header.forward();
  for (;;) {
    if (n == null)
      return false;
    **if (e.compareTo(n.element)) {**
```

I am writing a sorted list and am trying to insert the element at the correct location.

Node is Declared as:

```
class Node<E> extends AtomicReference<Node<E>> {
private volatile Node<E> prev;

final E element;
```

Comment: You only have to say `<E extends ...>` when you declare it ie the first time, after that it's just `<E>`

Comment: that works, however, the following statement now gives an error

    public boolean add(E e) {
    if (e.compare(n.element)) {

   cannot find symbol
     symbol:   method compare(E)
     location: variable e of type E
     where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Comparable<E> declared in class ConcurrentLinkedList

Comment: @AmarMond do you mean `e.compareTo`?  `Comparable` defines a `compareTo` method, not `compare`.

Comment: is `n.element` an `E`? If not you can't compare them. Can you add the code which doesn't compile to your question?

Comment: "the following code is now giving an error" - and that error is ...?

Comment: `compareTo` returns an `int`. You can’t say `if(intvalue)`; you need a relational operator, e.g. `if(e.compareTo(n.element)==0)` or `if(e.compareTo(n.element)>0)`, etc.